# Error loading a local file to a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load a local file into [BigQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) via the API, and it is failing. The file size is 98 MB and as a bit over 5 million rows. Note that I have loaded tables with the same number of rows and slightly bigger file size without problems in the past.

The code I am using is exactly the same as the one in the API documentation, which I have used successfully to upload several other tables. The error I get is the following:

```
Errors:
Line:2243530, Too few columns: expected 5 column(s) but got 3 column(s)
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
Job ID: job_6464fc24a4414ae285d1334de924f12d
Start Time: 9:38am, 7 Aug 2012
End Time: 9:38am, 7 Aug 2012
Destination Table: 387047224813:pos_dw_api.test
Source URI: uploaded file
Schema:
  tbId: INTEGER
  hdId: INTEGER
  vtId: STRING
  prId: INTEGER
  pff: INTEGER
```

Note that the same file loads just fine from CloudStorage (dw_tests/TestCSV/test.csv), so the problem cannot be the one reported about one line having fewer columns, as it would fail from CloudStorage too, and I have also checked that all the rows have the correct format.

The following jobs have the same problem, the only difference is the table name and the name of the fields in the schema are different (but it is the same data file, fields and types). In those attempts it claimed a different row in trouble:

```
Line:4288253, Too few columns: expected 5 column(s) but got 4 column(s)
```

The jobs are the following:

```
job_cbe54015b5304785b874baafd9c7e82e   load       FAILURE   07 Aug 08:45:23   0:00:34
job_f634cbb0a26f4404b6d7b442b9fca39c   load       FAILURE   06 Aug 16:35:28   0:00:30
job_346fdf250ae44b618633ad505d793fd1   load       FAILURE   06 Aug 16:30:13   0:00:34
```

The error that the Python script returns is the following:

```
{'status': '503', 'content-length': '177', 'expires': 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'server': 'HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 27 2012 15:58:36 (1343429916)', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'date': 'Tue, 07 Aug 2012 08:36:40 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

This looks like there may be an issue at BigQuery. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Juan: Just to be clear, are you getting the 503 error when the job is complete, and the "Line:4288253, Too few columns" when you inspect the failed ingestion job id?

Comment: Hi Michael, I get the 503 after a while, I guess at the point when it gets to the part of the file that cannot process. I got the details about "Line XXXXX too few colums" from the Jobs history in the console. Note that the job doesn't show in the history in the console until it has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary files were still around for this import, so I was able to check out the file we tried to import. For job `job_6464fc24a4414ae285d1334de924f12d`, the last lines were:

```
222,320828,bot,2,0
222,320829,bot,4,3
222,320829,
```

It looks like we dropped part of the input file at some point... The input specification says that the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash should be 58eb7c2954ddfa96d109fa1c60663293 but our hash of the data is 297f958bcf94959eae49bee32cc3acdc, and file size should be 98921024, but we only have 83886080 bytes.

I'll look into why this is occurring. In the meantime, imports though [Google Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Storage) use a much simpler path and should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. For a test I have just tried to upload a big file I successfully uploaded the other day (see job_c60decc9ff414a96aecf5367c7c60eb1) into a new table "387047224813:pos_dw_api.test2" and it has failed, the job was job_58d11425bafa4318844d8fb2c1d92c75. So this situation seems to be a recent development. Could the problem be on my end? maybe a comms issue with sockets being closed too early or similar?

Comment: The latest release (as of this afternoon) has some additional checks to see if we can catch this happening again. Can you give a try and let us know? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I have been able to load the same file now without problems (job_f15fe9fd42034349b944deb4590647b7). I have also tried the other big file that failed recently but that worked a few weeks ago and is working fine again too (job_44107a7c41c04f8f94f0917df734b6ed), so it seems that the issue is resolved. Thanks